# What is the covering density of a very thin annulus? Is it $\frac{\pi\sqrt{51\sqrt{17}-107}}{16}$?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, asymptotics

Take some very small $\epsilon>0$, and consider the annulus/ring given by the set $\{(r,\theta)\ |\ 1-\epsilon\le r\le1\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

We wish to place translated copies of this annulus down so that they cover the plane; obviously, this will cover some points multiple times, since the rings do not tile the plane without overlap. How can we do this to minimize the overall density, i.e., the number of times an average point is covered?

I can obtain a density of $\pi$ with the following construction (overlapping rings shown in darker shades):

[image]

However, it turns out this is suboptimal; we can do better by only placing $2/\epsilon$ of these rings in a line, and covering the plane with the resulting shapes:

[image]

This uses $2/\epsilon$ rings of area $2\pi\epsilon$ each, for a total area of $4\pi$, per $2\times 3$ rectangle in the tiling, so its density is $\frac{2\pi}3 \approx 2.094$.

We can improve this further by overlapping the above shapes vertically (as before, each of these is formed from $2/\epsilon$ rings):

[image]

A bit of calculus tells us this construction is optimized when the vertical overlap between two of the red regions is $2-\sqrt{\frac{3\sqrt{17}-5}2}$, for a total density of

$$\frac{\pi\sqrt{51\sqrt{17}-107}}{16}\approx 1.99954$$

Is this optimal? I'm curious about both improvements to this construction, and lower bounds that can be imposed on the density; so far I have not been able to establish lower bounds greater than $1$. Pointers to literature on this or related questions would also be welcome.

(It's fairly easy to show that a random point on a given annulus will be covered an average of at least $1+1/\pi$ times, but this oversamples multiply-covered points, so it doesn't tell us anything directly about the covering density.)

Comment: Now cross-posted to MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398390/what-is-the-covering-density-of-a-very-thin-annulus-is-it-frac-pi-sqrt51-sq).